# channelUrl error in Firefox addon while trying SE OAuth init

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon

I am trying to develop a Firefox addon that uses StackExchange API, using the client-side OAuth flow. I am just using the sample code found in StackApps documentation:

```
SE.init({ 
    clientId: 4267, 
    key: '8p1pDgmKlR6m6hUn80n21Q((', 
    channelUrl: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/proxy',
    complete: function(data) { 
        $('#login-button')
            .removeAttr('disabled')
            .text('Run Example With Version '+data.version); 
    }
});

...
```

When trying to run the addon, I receive the following error in the console:

`uncaught exception: channelUrl must be under the current domain`

I tried to change the domain to something else, matching it to the `OAuth Domain` value in my app registered at StackApps.com. I also tried disabling `Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri`. All to no avail.

So, how can I get rid of this error? Are Firefox extensions using their own hidden oauth domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with some experimentation.

It turns out that the channelUrl for a Firefox extension should be an internal resource file, in the form of:

`channelUrl = 'resource://<enstenion_id>-at-jetpack/<extension_name>/data/blank.html'`

Comment: can you share the OAuth domain used for stackapp? @lionstar